# named Cluster DNS breaking ssh

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, fedora, bind

This problem occurs on fedora core 12. So I was trying to setup a named dns server on a central node and on the surface it looks like it works (ping resolves, nslookup LOOKS like it gives correct info?), but I think I set it up wrong because hostbased passwordless ssh is having problems. The goal of the DNS server was to be a centralized internal DNS server for resolving names on the cluster and nothing else.

Here's what happens when I am on a machine and try to ssh into itself. Normally this works. Im pretty sure the issue is DNS related because when I add
 c0-0
to /etc/hosts, it all works because /etc/hosts has precedence over dns according to nsswitch.

Notice the getnameinfo error in the verbose ssh output.
http://pastebin.com/qSWFDtqf

Here's the same without the debug:
http://pastebin.com/svZmvakR

relevant named.conf lines (on central node):
http://pastebin.com/J08MPgBS

relevant cluster.dns lines (on central node):
http://pastebin.com/mtATKn1e

relevant /etc/hosts.equiv lines (i tried different variations of the hostname to see maybe if that was it):
c0-0
c0-0.
compute-0-00.local.
compute-0-00
compute-0-00.
compute-0-00.local
10.255.255.251

Like I said I'm pretty sure the error is in cluster.dns because I'm quite confused by the proper syntax. Does anyone see something trivial that I do not? Do I need to setup reverse DNS?

Comment: A little bit of a shot in the dark but, have you created reverse DNS records for these cluster nodes?

Comment: haha, I had just come in here to say that I'm 99% sure it's the lack of reverse DNS. I got one successful passwordless login.

Comment: Drop ssh from the troubleshooting and use dig to do a direct query on your DNS server to see if it is responding properly. Let us know what dig shows for the hostnames. You can use 'dig c0-0 @ip.of.dns.server' to query the server directly.

Comment: Yup, it was the lack of reverse DNS. It wasn't hard to slap together a script to map the existing /etc/hosts file into their respective forward and reverse dns zones. Thanks guys :P

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was missing reverse DNS. I usually disable DNS resolving for SSH every since I once tried to access my servers during a time where DNS was dead.

It took ages to log in - and I don`t like to be dependent from other infrastructure services that are not directly connected to the main purpose of my server.